# MVC3 Exposing repository functionality through service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been playing around with asp.net MVC3 a bit and have been struggling to decide where to place my business logic. I've settled on using a service layer for now:

```
    public class AnimalsService : IAnimalsService
    {
        private readonly IAnimalsRepository _animalsRepository;

        public AnimalsService(IAnimalsRepository animalsRepository)
        {
            _animalsRepository = animalsRepository;
        }
        public IQueryable<Animal> GetFiveLeggedAnimals()
        {
        ...
        }
    }
```

The controller would look something like this:

```
public class AnimalsController : Controller
{        
    private readonly IAnimalsService _animalsService;

    public AnimalsController(IAnimalsService animalsService)
    {
        _animalsService = animalsService;
    }

    public ViewResult ListFiveLeggedAnimals()
    {
        var animals = _animalsService.GetFiveLeggedAnimals();
        return View(animals);
    }
}
```

I have basic CRUD logic in the repository (All, Find, UpdateOrInsert, Delete). If I want to use these CRUD methods in my controller:

1) Do I have to create wrapper methods in the service for these respository calls?

2) Would it not make more sense for me to just include the GetFiveLeggedAnimals method and other business logic in the repository?

3) Could I implement the IAnimalsRepository interface in the AnimalsService and then call the base methods (I realise this is possible but I assume its bad practice)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Do I have to create wrapper methods in the service for these respository calls?

Mostly, yes. Typically, you want to offer CRUD for your domain models in the service layer. This way, the controller does not need to work with the repository directly (in fact, it never should). You can add more more sophisticated logic later without having to change external code. For example, consider you wanted to implement a newsfeed. Now every time a five-legged animal is inserted, you want to create a news item and push it to five-legged-animal-fans. Another common example is email notifications.

> 2) Would it not make more sense for me to just include the GetFiveLeggedAnimals method and other business logic in the repository?

Business logic should be in the *Service Layer* or in the *Domain Model* objects themselves, and only there. In fact (see 3), I wouldn't specifically offer an `IAnimalRepository` at all, if possible.

For instance, in a NoSQL-Environment, the database driver pretty much *is* a repository. On the other hand, when using a complex ORM mapping and stored procedures (where part of the biz logic is in the DB), you don't really have a choice but offer explicit interfaces that know the stored procedures.

I'd go for a `IRepository<T>` and use the *Query Object* pattern, if possible. I think *LINQ* can also be considered a *Query Object* / *Repository* based pattern.

> 3) Could I implement the IAnimalsRepository interface in the AnimalsService and then call the base methods (I realise this is possible but I assume its bad practice)?

To call the *base* methods, you'd have to inherit from a concrete implementation, e.g. from `ConcreteAnimalsRepository`.

Also, if your service implements the `IAnimalsRepository` interface directly or indirectly, it makes the (unfiltered) CRUD operations available to everyone.

My take: **Don't inherit, aggregate**. A service layer *has* a repository, but it *isn't* a repository itself: The service layer handles all the additional application logic (permissions, notifications) and the repository is a very thin wrapper around the db layer.

As an extreme example, what if deleting something directly was forbidden, and only the service would be allowed to make use of it when inserting a newer revision of sth.? This can be easily built when aggregating.

Answer (score 1):

Repository by definition should be a generic collection-like class that abstracts DB interactions. It would contain typical methods for persistence like `Get(object id), Add(T), Remove(T)` and possibly implement `IQueryable<T>`.

The service would look like the following code.

```
public class AnimalsService : IAnimalsService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Animal> _repository;

    public AnimalsService(IRepository<Animal> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Animal> GetFiveLeggedAnimals()
    {
     // animal specific business logic
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using IAnimalRepository as it was scaffolded when I first created my project. Found an interesting link on the topic http://richarddingwall.name/2009/01/19/irepositoryt-one-size-does-not-fit-all/. For my project a generic repository suits me better - I'll replace the individual ones :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think is not good to use simple CRUD operation in the Controller and have a wrapper in the Service class, you should keep all business logic in the service layer, not in controller
for example you want to create a new Animal
in the controller you will have method

look at the example

```
    // not good design
public ActionResult Create(AnimalInput input)
{
     Animal animal = new Animal { Name = input.Name}; // set the other propreties
    // if you have a CRUD operations in service class you will call
    animalService.UpdateOrInsert(animal);

}
// better disign
public ActionResult Create(AnimalInput input)
{

    animalService.Create(input.Name);

}
```

in the service class implementation you should have
follow

```
public void Create(string name)
  {
    Animal animal = new Animal { Name = input.Name};
   animalRepository.UpdateOrInsert(animal);
  }
```

for the methods like GetAll or GetFiveLeggedAnimals();  you can have wrapper in the service classes I think it's ok . And I want to give you adives allways when you write some code in controller or in Service class keep in mind how you will test this code 
and don't forget about [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29)

Comment: Why should this be a better design? It completely violates encapsulation, and makes the interface way too complicated. It requires you to construct two objects instead of one, it requires copy constructors or mapping, it is likely not to work with objects that can have complicated state information and business logic (i.e., with a complex domain model).

Comment: Did you mean that the logic for creation of domain object in the controller it is good design? If yes I don't agree all business logic should be in the service classes if you use this architecture, if use DDD the business logic should be in the domain. that all what I mean in my answer.

Comment: Imagine that you need to change the MVC application in the WinForms application,if some logic keep in controller classes then you have to rewrite code from controller in new WinForms application, if all logic keep in the services classes there will be need just call methods of service classes in  WinForm app

Comment: You're missing the point. If you need to use a domain object from different types of applications then it's very likely that you won't do it in a similar way. A web application is stateless, and requires different view models and different construction patterns than a stateful desktop application. I think Martin Fowler wrote "Service layers have coarse-grained interfaces almost by definition". Don't overvalue reusability -- encapsulation is key, and object construction should be simple anyways.

Comment: @mnemosyn The most advantage for me using Repository/Service is code readability. First it seems that you duplicate the code and classes but later it will pay you twice.

Comment: @Tomas: please look at my answer to this q where I recommend `IRepository`. I'm not saying repository is an antipattern. However, Serghei recommends to create the domain model object within the service layer, which creates very tightly coupled interfaces with long parameter lists. The alternative would be to pass a DTO to the service layer and have the service layer create the domain model. But then, all biz logic operations in the domain model would have to be mapped to a respective service layer op. That has nothing to do with the repository, but with anemic domain models and tight coupling.